# Print Multiple panels using javascript in asp.net c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, printing, panel

I have 3 panels in my page, I want each panel to be printed in different page, not in the same page.(I meant Panel 1 in page 1 & panel 2 in page 2 & panel 3 in page 3).
what happened now is that the first panel is printed and panel 2 is printed in the same page.
How can I print each one in different seperated page?

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
 <script type = "text/javascript">

       function PrintPanel() {

           var panel = document.getElementById("<%=Panel1.ClientID %>");
           var panel2 = document.getElementById("<%=Panel2.ClientID %>");
           var panel3 = document.getElementById("<%=Panel3.ClientID %>");


           var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'scrollbars=yes,     resizable=yes, width=800, height=500');

          printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>My Title</title>');

        printWindow.document.write('</head><body >');

        printWindow.document.write(panel.innerHTML);
        printWindow.document.write(panel2.innerHTML);
        printWindow.document.write(panel3.innerHTML);             
        printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');

        printWindow.document.close();

        setTimeout(function () {

            printWindow.print();

        }, 500);

          return false;

    }

</script>
```

Comment: I updated my question to have the code

Comment: The fact that they open in same window is because you are using the same `printWindow` object for all of them. Hence, it uses the same window to write evey panel. Do a loop or make separate window objects and try.

Comment: but it will open the window 3 times, which I don't want!

Comment: Then what does 3 separate pages mean here ?

Comment: @user1947393, are you referring to different printed pages from printer? Each panel should be on different printer pages?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create three separate windows to print the panels like below-

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function PrintPanel() {
    var panel1 = "<h1>Test1</h1>";
    var panel2 = "<h1>Test2</h1>";
    var panel3 = "<h1>Test3</h1>";

    var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=800,height=500');

    var iframe1 = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe1.id = 'iframe1';
    iframe1.name = 'iframe1';
    printWindow.document.body.appendChild(iframe1);
    iframe1.contentWindow.document.write(panel1);

    var iframe2 = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe2.id = 'iframe2';
    iframe2.name = 'iframe2';
    printWindow.document.body.appendChild(iframe2);
    iframe2.contentWindow.document.write(panel2);

    var iframe3 = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe3.id = 'iframe3';
    iframe3.name = 'iframe3';
    printWindow.document.body.appendChild(iframe3);
    iframe3.contentWindow.document.write(panel3);

    printWindow.document.close();
    setTimeout(function () {
        for (var k = 0; k < printWindow.frames.length; k++) {
            printWindow.frames[k].focus();
            printWindow.frames[k].print();
        }
    }, 500);
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Should have read the comment above. Would have saved your time.

Comment: No problem. The OP is trying something else. This is the first thing that comes in mind. :)

Comment: yeah i think he wants three panels to be printed on seperate pages, just a thought :)

Comment: Yes I want the three panels to be printed on seperate pages & one window to be opened for printing. my page is just like 3 parts, each part in one panel, I want them all to be printed at the same time but each one on seperate page. if I'm going to use three separate windows, it means the window will be opened 3 times which doesn't look like one document to the user.

Comment: @user1947393, sorry I didn't had the time yesterday to look into this, but I have updated the code. In this you need to have multiple iframes to keep separate htmls of the panels and then print them seperately. Note you'll get three dialog boxes for printing of each iframe which you cannot simply restrict using javascript. Hope this helps :)